# How to set initial values only to extra fields in a Django inline formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am fairly new to **Django** and **Python** so please bear with me. I am trying to create a tabular timesheet form like below.

Timesheet Form:

[image]

**Expected result**

What I am trying to achieve is, when I call a particular timesheet I should get all related timesheet details data and populate above form in a way that all hours related to a combination of workdate/project will be in the same row and related hours are placed under the corresponding workcode (i.e. in pic row1 would have 8 hours under 'Norm', row2 would have 12 hours under RnR)

**Problems**

Now how can I set initial value to populate correct hour cells (not related to model field) in each row with hours depending on the workcode for that combination of workday/project?

Secondly how do I handle if the hours are split hours(e.g. norm 4 hours and Annu 4 hours) for same workday/project? How do I put the in same Row? If I could use a dictionary to populate this would be easy?

Since I do not have any initial data in the form for 10/80/20... fields I can not check if any hours were deleted so that I could delete that record too.

I have started to question myself If my approach with inline forest is even valid in this scenario?

So the bottomline is how do I populate these unrelated form fields in this form?

I am open to any approach or ideas to get this working and appreciate your help.

If you find I have done something wrong please feel free to correct me so that I can learn.

**Code**

Models.py

```
class Workcode(models.Model):
    workcode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    workcode_description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    workcode_short = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    workcode_serial = models.SmallIntegerField()

class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class WeekendDate(models.Model):
    weekenddate = models.DateField(unique=True)

class Timesheet(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    weekenddate = models.ForeignKey(WeekendDate)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('employee', 'weekenddate')

class TimesheetDetail(models.Model):
    timesheet = models.ForeignKey(Timesheet)
    workcode = models.ForeignKey(Workcode)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    workdate = models.DateField()
    hours = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('timesheet','workcode','project','workdate')
```

forms.py

```
class TimesheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Timesheet
        fields = "__all__"

class BaseTimesheetInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseTimesheetInlineFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['10']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='Norm', required=False)
        form.fields['80']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='RnR', required=False)
        form.fields['20']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='Annu', required=False)
        form.fields['21']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='Sick', required=False)
        form.fields['25']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label="Carer", required=False)
        form.fields['26']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='LSL', required=False)
        form.fields['13']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='Night', required=False)
        form.fields['14']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label="Noon", required=False)
        form.fields['71']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='Bus', required=False)
        form.fields['22']   = forms.IntegerField(max_value=16, min_value=0, label='WComp', required=False)



TimesheetDetailInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(models.Timesheet,
                                                models.TimesheetDetail,
                                                form = TimesheetForm,
                                                formset=BaseTimesheetInlineFormSet,
                                                # fields=('workdate','project'),
                                                fields='__all__',
                                                extra=7, max_num=9)
```

views.py

```
def manage_timesheet1(request, timesheet_id):
"""Edit children and their addresses for a single parent."""

initial_data = [{'workcode': 1, 'project':1, 'workdate': '2017-12-29', 'hours':10, },
                {'workcode': 1, 'project':1, 'workdate': '2017-12-30', 'hours':8, }]

timesheet = Timesheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = TimesheetDetailInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=timesheet)

    if formset.is_valid():

        # This development will be in a saperate branch called 'alternet-time-save'#
        converted_data = []
        wc_list = ['10','80','20,','21','25','26','13','14','71','22']
        # with transaction.atomic():
        for form in formset:
            if form.has_changed():
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.timesheet = timesheet
                obj.workcode = Workcode.objects.get(id=5)
                for k,v in form.cleaned_data.items():
                    if k in wc_list and k in form.changed_data:
                        if v is not None:
                            obj, created = TimesheetDetail.objects.update_or_create(
                                    # pk = form.cleaned_data['id'].id,
                                    timesheet = timesheet,
                                    workcode = Workcode.objects.get(workcode=k),
                                    project = form.cleaned_data['project'],
                                    workdate = form.cleaned_data['workdate'],
                                    defaults = {
                                        'timesheet' : timesheet,
                                        'workcode' : Workcode.objects.get(workcode=k),
                                        'project' : form.cleaned_data['project'],
                                        'workdate' : form.cleaned_data['workdate'],
                                        'hours' : v
                                        })

        return redirect('timesheet:timesheetlist')
    else:
        print(formset.errors)
else:
    # formset = TimesheetDetailInlineFormset(instance=timesheet, initial=initial_data)
    formset = TimesheetDetailInlineFormset(instance=timesheet)


if request.is_ajax():
    return render(request, 'timesheet/_ajax_manage_timesheet.html', {
                  'children_formset':formset, 'timesheetid':timesheet_id})
else:
    return render(request, 'timesheet/manage_timesheet.html', {
                  'children_formset':formset, 'timesheetid':timesheet_id})
```

Comment: Humm....someone down voted with out any comment? is it normally how it works here? how would I know what I did wrong without a comment?

Comment: I ended up here with similar issue. Any improvement?

Comment: I had the same requirements to manage timesheet for employee/contractors with related project or routine works.
I would move workdate into column with two fields: selectable job code, hour